# Is there a way to list all the input variables for a terraform resource?

Tags: terraform

I want to get a list of all the variables (optional or not) and ideally their defaults defined in a resource. Say in the AWS provider, but need anything. I know I can get and look at the documentation (which doesn't list everything I want) or the raw provider code and find all this, but is there a utility that would list this for me?

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do here? It might be easier if you give more context and an example.

Answer (score 0):

The [schemas-extractor from the Hashicorp Terraform / HCL Language plugin source](https://github.com/VladRassokhin/intellij-hcl/blob/master/schemas-extractor/fetch-providers.sh) builds a machine readable schema document for all providers in the terraform[-providers org on GitHub](https://github.com/terraform-providers/).

The [Terraform LSP](https://github.com/juliosueiras/terraform-lsp) is another likely source of this information.